# Ajax synchronous call returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a simple javascript function to retrieve a webpage content using ajax and yql. Here's the function:

```
function retrieveDataGet(url){
    var encodedUrl = encodeURI(url);
    var address = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+encodedUrl+"%2Fcategory%2Fnews%2F%22&diagnostics=true";
    console.log("Call : "+address+"\n");
    $.ajax({
        url: address,
        method: 'GET',
        async: false
    }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);//Here I can see the webpage data
    return data;
    }).error(function(err){
        return "Error";
    }).fail(function(){
        return "Fail";
    });
}
```

Now, when I call the function, I can see the data on the console printed by the instruction "console.log(data)", but when I try this code:

```
var data = retrieveDataGet("http://www.wikipedia.org/");
console.log(data);//here data is undefined
```

I get "undefined".

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it in that way:

do like this:

```
var MyData;

retrieveDataGet("http://www.wikipedia.org/");

console.log(MyData);
```

little modification in function:

```
function retrieveDataGet(url){
    var encodedUrl = encodeURI(url);
    var address = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+encodedUrl+"%2Fcategory%2Fnews%2F%22&diagnostics=true";
    console.log("Call : "+address+"\n");
    $.ajax({
          url: address,
          method: 'GET',
          async: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);//Here I can see the webpage data
            MyData = data;
        }).error(function(err){
                return "Error";
            }).fail(function(){
                return "Fail";
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, solved. Why I have to do this, and I cannot return the value from my function? It is a javascript language related issue?

Comment: the issue is you cannot return from ajax function values

Answer (score -1):

```
function retrieveDataGet(url){
var returnData = "";
    var encodedUrl = encodeURI(url);
    var address = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+encodedUrl+"%2Fcategory%2Fnews%2F%22&diagnostics=true";
    console.log("Call : "+address+"\n");
    $.ajax({
          url: address,
          method: 'GET',
          async: false
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);//Here I can see the webpage data
            returnData  = data;
        }).error(function(err){
               returnData  = "Error";
            }).fail(function(){
                  returnData  = "Fail";
            });
return returnData ;
}
```

Check this. 
Please note - 
It is better to have one return statement for a function.
In Ajax, return the data in success callback.